# Calcular valor entre <h> usando jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

Bom dia,
Tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<section id="four" class="wrapper special">
    <div class="inner">
           <div class="features" id="Comprando">
              <div class="feature">
       <h3>Produto1</h3>
       <b>R$ <?php echo round($valor1, 3); ?></b>
              <input type="text" class="reais">
              <input type="text" class="resultado" readonly>
              </div>
               <div class="feature">
       <h3>Produto2</h3>
       <b>R$ <?php echo round($valor2, 3); ?></b>
              <input type="text" class="reais">
              <input type="text" class="resultado" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</section>
```

Basicamente o valor do produto vem de uma váriável ($valor), a pessoal coloca quantos reais ela quer gastar (input class="reais") e o jquery executa uma divisão entre o input e a variável, e o resultado sai em input class="resultado". Isso cada vez que a pessoa preenche o input reais e pra cada div, ou seja, pra cada produto.
Quem puder ajudar, agradeço desde já!

Comment: e por que não calcula no PHP (sem o `round`) e joga com echo no tal input?

Comment: o usuário vai inputar o quanto quer gastar, n tenho essa informação antes

Comment: O php retorna o valor do produto. O usuário coloca o quanto quer gastar e o jquery retorna a divisão desses dois.

Comment: Ué, deixa o valor salvo em um input hidden sem round e sem mascara, ai é só pegar o valor do `$('input[name=valor]').val()` e calcular.

Comment: Huuummmm entendi, vou tentar. Agradecido!!